# OSX launchctl , how to stop a job upon unload

Tags: node.js, macos, launchd

Currently I am starting aGhost npm server using forever and a LaunchAgent

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
    <plist version="1.0">  
    <dict>  
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>rhino.forever.ghost</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>                              
          <string>..../bin/node</string>
          <string>..../bin/forever</string>
          <string>start</string
          <string>-w</string>
          <string>..../index.js</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>  
    </plist>
```

starting it with :

```
 launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/rhino.forever.ghost.plist
```

But it does not stop when unloading it :

```
 launchctl unload  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/rhino.forever.ghost.plist
```

Is there anyway to stop it when unloading ???

thanks for feedback

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: no, but I resolved to start / restart /stop it using bash aliases,  see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I resolved to start | stop | restart my ghost app 'rhino' with aliases in .bash_aliases

```
alias rhino.dev.start="nginx.start; 
  cd /Users/..../myghostapp;
  ~/.../bin/forever start -aw --uid 'rhino' index.js; 
  forever list"

alias rhino.dev.stop="forever stop 'rhino' ; nginx.stop"

alias rhino.dev.restart="forever restart 'rhino' ; nginx.restart"
```

running fine now